# casting std::function to a different std::function and invoking it?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, casting, arguments

I have a question about casting an std::function of one type to another with the same number of arguments or more and then invoking it since it works on all the compilers but i am not sure if it is a defined behavior.

```
std::function<void(int, float)> func1 = [](int a, float b){
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
  std::cout << b << std::endl;
};

std::function<void(int, float, int, double)>& func2 =
*reinterpret_cast<std::function<void(int, float, int, double)>*>(&func1);

func2(1, 2.0f, 3, 4.0);
```

This seems to properly call func1 with the expected args  1, 2.0f. What happens to the other passed arguments. What happens when i swap func1 and func2 and invoke it with 2 arguments when it is expecting 4. Is it a well defined behaviour since it works on msvc, gcc, clang or is it some kind of fluke and i should avoid it. Can anyone with more expertise elaborate on the topic?

Comment: What's the use case ? Just curious.

Comment: the idea was to be able to subscribe to an event by string and to be able to expect equal or less arguments from that event. Here is the code for the event dispatcher:
'

Answer (score 3):

> This seems to properly call `func1` [...]

You cannot cast a `std::function<Sig1>` to a `std::function<Sig2>`. They are unrelated types, despite being specializations of the same function template. One cannot simply refer to the other. It's undefined behavior. One potential consequence of undefined behavior is that the code does seem to work. And then you change compilers. Or compiler versions. Or just some random unrelated code that causes the optimizer to do different things. Or...

If you want a new function with a new signature, you have to create a new function object. One way, if you want to simply drop the last two arguments, would be:

```
std::function<void(int, float, int, double)> func2 = [func1](int a, float b, int, double){
    func1(a, b);
};
```

Another would be to take advantage of the fact that `bind` simply drops unused arguments:

```
std::function<void(int, float, int, double)> func2 = std::bind(func1, _1, _2);
```

Both of these are fine.

Answer (score 3):

the idea was to be able to subscribe to an event by string and to be able to expect equal or less arguments from that event. Here is the code for the event dispatcher that had the questionable functionality. I was thinking that this would work due to the implementation details of std::function having a constant size and the way its internal buffer works which is fixed and either stores the captures if it has the size or it stores the pointer to heap allocated storage for the captures which would explain why the reinterpret cast works but i am unsure what happens with the extra parameters when the function is called.

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

template <typename F>
struct function_traits : public function_traits<decltype(&F::operator())>
{};

template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<R(T::*)(Args...) const>
{
    typedef R(*pointer)(Args...);
    typedef R return_type;
    static constexpr std::size_t arg_count = sizeof...(Args);
    typedef std::tuple<Args...> args_tuple;
    typedef const std::function<R(Args...)> function;
};

struct function_wrapper
{
    virtual ~function_wrapper() {}
    virtual const void* get_ptr() const= 0;
};

template<typename F>
class function_wrapper_t : public function_wrapper
{
public:
    function_wrapper_t(F&& f) : _function(f) {}
    ~function_wrapper_t() {}
    const void* get_ptr() const { return &_function; }

private:
    typename function_traits<F>::function _function;
};

template <typename F>
std::unique_ptr<function_wrapper> create_wrapper(F f)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<function_wrapper_t<decltype(f)>>(new function_wrapper_t<decltype(f)>(std::forward<F>(f)));
}

class event_dispatcher
{
public:
    template<typename F>
    void connect(const std::string& name, F f)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<void, typename function_traits<F>::return_type>::value,
            "Signals cannot have a return type different from void");

        _list[name].emplace_back(create_wrapper(std::forward<F>(f)));
    }

    template<typename ... Args>
    void dispatch(const std::string& name, Args... args)
    {
        auto& funcs = _list[name];

        for (auto& func : funcs)
        {
            auto& f = *reinterpret_cast<const std::function<void(Args...)>*>(func->get_ptr());
            f(std::forward<Args>(args) ...); // is this undefined behavior?
        }
    }
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<function_wrapper>>> _list;
};

int main()
{
    event_dispatcher d;
    d.connect("test_event", [](int a, float b)
    {

    });
    d.connect("test_event", [](int a)
    {

    });

    d.dispatch("test_event", 1, 2.0f, 3, 4.0);
}
```